# Sailsjs blueprints is not catching error generated by "beforeCreate" or "beforeUpdate" Models Functions

Tags: node.js, sails.js

When i throw an error from the lifeCycle fn "beforeCreate" of any model, blueprint (default api of sails) not throw the error to the request.

When some model validation not pass, blueprint throw error 400 and show error but when i throw an error from beforeCreate, this not throw 400 and not throw the same format error and i need the same error response in the controller (blueprint)

im using Sailsjs 1.0.1

```
//models/item.js

module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    nombre: { type: 'string', required: true },
    empresa: { model: 'empresa', required: true },
  },
  beforeCreate: async (values, proceed) => {
    let nameUsed = await Item.count({ nombre: values.nombre, empresa: values.empresa });
    if (nameUsed > 0) return proceed('ERROR, NAME ALREADY USED FOR THE CURRENT EMPRESA')
    return proceed()
  }

};
```